# Add a new column to multiple dataframes using a for loop

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
library lubridate

eventtime<-c("2020-02-07 22:06:00","2020-02-07 22:00:00","2020-02-07 21:46:00")
eventvalue<-c("home","work",'exit')
geof<-data.frame(eventtime,eventvalue)
```

Then I gather all its unique `eventvalue` values to a new one.

```
geoun<-data.frame(unique(geof$eventvalue))
```

I create new dataframes one for each unique `eventvalue`

```
#Create dataframes according to eventvalue
for(i in 1:nrow(geoun)){
  assign(paste0(geoun[i,1]), data.frame(geof[ which(geof$eventvalue==geoun[i,1]), ]))

}
```

Then I want to repeat the process below-adding a new column- for each one using a for loop.

```
#extract just the hour maker, so we can count by hour
home$EventHour <- hour(home$eventtime)
```

I use:

```
#Create dataframes according to eventvalue
for(i in 1:nrow(geoun)){
  assign(paste0(geoun[i,1]), data.frame(geof[ which(geof$eventvalue==geoun[i,1]), ])$EventHour)<- hour(assign(paste0(geoun[i,1]), data.frame(geof[ which(geof$eventvalue==geoun[i,1]), ]))$eventtime)

}
```

but I get:

```
Error in assign(paste0(geoun[i, 1]), data.frame(geof[which(geof$eventvalue ==  : 
  could not find function "assign<-"
```

How can I achieve that. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier would be to use a list instead of assigning different data.frames. I think something like this will give the same answer:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

list1 <- geof %>%
  split(.$eventvalue) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(EventHour = hour(eventtime)) %>%
  split(.$eventvalue)
```

Edit:

You can assign the list elements to different data.frames using:

```
for (i in names(list1)) setNames(assign(i, data.frame(list1[[i]])), names(list1))
```

Comment: how can I save each one of the 3 dataframes produced?